# get value from $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling temperature reading from my temp.php and displaying it on my index.php with the code below.
My problem is I cannot use the information for anything else
I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<div id = "temperature"></div>  // displays as expected

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#temperature").load('temp.php')
}, 1000);
});

temp1 = document.getElementById('temperature').value; // this doesn't work
if (temp1 == 72) {do something}; //cannot get the value of "temperature"
```

Comment: `<div>` s don’t have a `value`, but are you trying to run this right away without waiting for the load to finish?

Comment: The information I am getting from "temp.php" is updated every second. I want to continuously compare with "if".

Answer (score -1):

You should get the response in the callback like the following

```
<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what I am having issues with is, getting the data in "temperature" or "success" in your case and using it in ... if (success == 72) {do something};

Comment: Do you get the response in json or text or xml? If you want to use the resonse in the div should be like innerHTML not value since temperature is not form element.

Comment: it is getting the response from an echo on the temp.php page, so i assume it's text.

Comment: yes, I tried x = document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML;